# EnvironmentError when installing package rdap with pip on windows

Tags: python, pip, rdap

I want to install the module `rdap` according to instructions in github [here](https://pypi.org/project/rdap/). I get the following error, with the command `pip install rdap` in cmd:

> Collecting rdap   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/8f/38ebde98eecf836c57727faccaef3b10be44ddfe9b2f5192b789e1792d89/rdap-0.5.0.tar.gz
>
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 267]
> Nom de rÚpertoire non valide:
> 'C:\Users\AGENIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n7gubvsj\rdap\Ctl/tmp/git@github.com:20c'

the error message translates: "folder name not valid" (prob. equivalent to no such file or directory..)
Here is the result of `IPython.sys_info()`:

```
{'commit_hash': '8c47bbcb3',
 'commit_source': 'installation',
 'default_encoding': '1252',
 'ipython_path': 'C:\\Users\\AGENIS\\Anaconda3\\envs\\python_35_for_rdap\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython',
 'ipython_version': '7.5.0',
 'os_name': 'nt',
 'platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0',
 'sys_executable': 'C:\\Users\\AGENIS\\Anaconda3\\envs\\python_35_for_rdap\\python.exe',
 'sys_platform': 'win32',
 'sys_version': '3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC '
                'v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'}
```

I don't understand what's going on with this error. I'm admin of my computer. I can successfully get any other package installed without error.

**EDIT:** this was a bug, reported and fixed in package version 0.5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The archive `rdap-0.5.0.tar.gz` contains a subdirectory `rdap-0.5.0/Ctl/tmp/git@github.com:20c/`. The name is invalid because it contains `:` — a forbidden character in w32 (because of `C:`).

This is a bug in the package. Please report it at https://github.com/20c/rdap/issues.

Comment: OK the bug is now fixed. Thanks for your help.